# Binary encoding or padding the input sequence in neural network?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, vectorization

First of all, I'm new to deep learning and neural networks but I could not find an answer to this question on the web. I'm trying to categorize the Reuters dataset of Keras, and it turned out when I'm padding the sequence input like below:

```
x_train = pad_sequences(x_train, maxlen=10000)
x_test = pad_sequences(x_test, maxlen=10000)
```

the accuracy would not exceed 42%; however, using the same model when I do 
binary vectorization, the accuracy would go up to 95%. Here is the binary vectorization code:

```
def vectorize_sequences(sequences, dimension=10000):
    results = np.zeros((len(sequences), dimension))
    for i, sequence in enumerate(sequences):
        results[i, sequence] = 1.
    return results

x_train = vectorize_sequences(x_train)
x_test = vectorize_sequences(x_test)
```

And here are the layers:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation="relu", input_shape=x_train[0].shape))
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.Dense(46, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss=losses.categorical_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=512, epochs=20)
```

What is the difference between these two methods that make this huge difference in the result? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Reuters dataset in Keras is represented as integer indices of words. For example, the text "On Friday there was a wildfire in California" has been represented as an array `[7, 18, 3, 673, 2, 73, 89, 7643]` (i.e. one integer index corresponding to each word). This kind of representation is useful for models which can map these integers to a numerical representation, for example models containing embedding layers. However, they would not perform well when you feed them as input to densely connected neural networks which does not have a mapping mechanism. That's because those kind of neural networks have not been designed to work well with such an input representation.

On the other hand, the second approach you are using represents each text as a vector of zeros and ones, where the value of 1 indicates the presence of a word and the value of 0 indicates the absence of a word (this is called bag-of-words representation). For example, if the value of index 10 in the vector is 1, then this means that word with index 10 is present in that document. And the good news is that the densely connected neural networks like in your question are very good at handling such representation and training over those kind of input representations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Is there any resource I can read to understand the relation between layer and input representation? because I can't find anything explaining this.

Comment: @MohammadSiavashi Well, that's essentially the machine learning education. You need to become familiar with different input representations and which model is suitable for each of them. There are many machine learning books. However, a more practical approach is to read the tutorials available on the web. There are lots of them. For example, just search "text classification keras" or "text classification embedding keras" or "text classification keras bag of words", etc.